# Mediawiki parser and recursiveTagParse

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have an issue with rendering wikitext in hook for tag processing.

```
public static function onTagRender( $input, array $args, $parser, $frame ) {
...
$text = $parser->recursiveTagParse($sometext, $frame);
...
return $text;
}
```

If $sometext contains e.g.

```
"Example from page [[XYZ]]"
```

then I expect returned $text should contain

```
"Example from page <a href="/wiki/XYZ" title="XYZ">XYZ</a>"
```

But I get only

```
"Example from page <!--LINK 0:0-->"
```

I have tried also $parser->replaceInternalLinks(), but with same result. What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

If some people run into the same problem, try calling **`replaceLinkHolders`** after `recursiveTagParse`. (I didn't have the same problem so I didn't test it.)

So in OP's code snippet, that would be:

```
public static function onTagRender( $input, array $args, $parser, $frame ) {
...
$text = $parser->recursiveTagParse($sometext, $frame);
$text = $parser->replaceLinkHolders($text);
...
return $text;
}
```

**Explanation according to my understanding:**

Actually, the usual `parse` method calls the `internalParse` method -- which does most of the job -- and then do some other stuff. On the other hand, `recursiveTagParse` is almost only calling `internalParse`, so it doesn't execute the other stuff from `parse`.
Problem is, links are parsed in two steps:

1. Links are first extracted into `LinkHolderArray` and they are replaced with `<!--LINK $ns:$key-->` in the text.
   *(This is done by `replaceInternalLinks`, called by `internalParse`, so that's fine.)*
2. Then `<!--LINK $ns:$key-->` markers are parsed into HTML links.
   *(This is done by `replaceLinkHolders` which is called by `parse`, not by `internalParse`, and thus not by `recursiveTagParse`.)*

Answer (score 0):

Parser::recursiveTagParse only do partial rendering, afaik. That may or may not be the problem. To fully render any user input, you will have to create a parser function (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions) instead of a tag function.

See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions#How_do_I_render_wikitext_in_my_extension.3F